# Flutter - Argument of type function can't be assigned to the parameter of type `void function()`

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a `StatelessWidget` for `ElevatedButton()` and I get this error  `Argument of type function can't be assigned to the parameter of type void function()` when I pass a `selectHandler` to the `onPressed` argument of `ElevatedButton()`. The `selectHandler` is a `Function` type variable.

Where am I going wrong?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {

  final Function selectHandler;

  Answer(this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text("Answer"), 
        onPressed: selectHandler
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`onPressed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyleButton/onPressed.html) is expecting a `void Function()` (aka [`VoidCallback`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/VoidCallback.html)), but the type of `selectedHandler` does not specify the function's parameter list or return type.

You could specify the type as `final void Function() selectHandler`, which means a function that takes no parameters and returns `void`.

Flutter also provides the type `VoidCallback` as part of [`dart:ui`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/VoidCallback.html) which is the same as `void Function()`, so you could use that as well, in which case your type becomes `final VoidCallback selectHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to accept a VoidCallback instead of Function for the onPressed.
By the way VoidCallback is just shorthand for void Function() so you could also define it as final void Function() onPressed;

Updated code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {

final VoidCallback selectHandler;

Answer(this.selectHandler);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
width: double.infinity,
child: ElevatedButton(
child: Text("Answer"),
onPressed: selectHandler
)
);
}
}