# Got this error while passing callback function in flutter, Can anyone solve this

Tags: flutter, dart

Here I'm trying to make a Begginer quiz app.
Trying to have a seperate file for each widget.
in the process, using callback function i got error and cannot find a way solve.

'''

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'question.dart';
import 'answer.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _questionIndex = 0;
  void _answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
     });

    print(_questionIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      'What\'s your choice of color ?',
      'What\'s your choice of animal'
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
       home: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
          title: (Text('Quiz time')),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
        
            Question(
              questions[_questionIndex],
             ),
            Answer(_answerQuestion),
            Answer(_answerQuestion),
            Answer(_answerQuestion),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

file name= answer.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {

  final Function selectHandler;
  Answer(this.selectHandler);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container(
       width: double.infinity,
       child: ElevatedButton(
       child: Text('Answer 1'),       

       onPressed:selectHandler,

**here in selectHandler it is showing error**
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

'''
The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: It is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67762455/flutter-argument-of-type-function-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-of-type)
You need to call a function like this ;

```
final void Function() selectHandler; // instead of final Function selectHandler;
```

or also you can use below. These 2 solutions are same;

```
final VoidCallback selectHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your selectHandler type to `VoidCallback` and it should be ok

```
  final VoidCallback selectHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple you have to update this line in **Answer.dart** file.

```
final Function selectHandler;
```

Replace this line with

```
final VoidCallback selectHandler;
```

This line will be solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

use 'final VoidCallback selectHandler' instead if 'final Function selectHandler'

Comment: with explanations also you can add some code sample

Comment: This has already been suggested by the other answers.